# Google App Engine render and Django forms

Tags: google-app-engine, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use Django forms in my Google App Engine project, using the template system.  However I can't figure out how to get forms to be rendered properly.  When calling form.as_p () from python code I get the expected html,

```
<p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" /></p>
```

yet when calling form.as_p from the template I instead get

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;id_name&quot;&gt;Name:&lt;/label&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; name=&quot;name&quot; id=&quot;id_name&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Here is my render method

```
def render(self, name, **data):
    """Render a template"""
    if not data:
        data = {}
    self.response.out.write(template.render(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', name + '.html'),
        data))
```

Render method being called:

```
form = PostForm()
self.render('toplevel', parent=user, items=user.establishments(), form=form)
```

And finally the template:

```
{% block content %}

    {{ form.as_p }}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form in the template to:

```
{% block content %}

    {{ form.as_p|safe }}

{% endblock content %}
```

That should prevent the HTML in as_p from being escaped. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe